# Google Maps API V3 function closure for loops for markers

Tags: javascript, google-maps, closures

I have been reading other entries into stackoverflow but I really cannot get my head around how this works:

```
            for(a in elements){
                var address = elements[a].location;                       

                var contentString = '<table>';

                for(b in elements[a].other_fields){
                    var current = elements[a].other_fields[b];

                    switch(current.type){
                        case "text":
                            contentString += "<tr><td class = 'the_title'>" + current.label + ":</td><td class = 'the_value'>" + current.values[0].value + "</td></tr>";
                        break;
                        case "date":
                            if(!current.values[0].end){
                                var end_date_output_string = "";
                            }else{ 
                                var end_date_output_string = " -> " + current.values[0].end;
                            }
                            contentString += "<tr><td class = 'the_title'>" + current.label + ":</td><td class = 'the_value'>" + current.values[0].start + end_date_output_string + "</td></tr>";
                        break;
                    }
                }

                contentString += "</table>";  
                contentString += "<input type = 'button' onclick = 'window.open(\"" + elements[a].url + "\");' value = 'Open in Podio'>";

                geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
                    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                        map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                        alert(contentString);
                        addMarker(results[0].geometry.location);    
                    } else {
                        alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
                    }
                });      
                //open_info_window(a, contentString);  
            } 



                                function addMarker(location) {
                                    var marker_copy = new google.maps.Marker({
                                        position: location, 
                                        map: map 
                                    });   

                                    marker = marker_copy;

                                    markersArray.push({
                                        "marker": marker,
                                        "info_window": null
                                    });  

                                    alert("marker added: " + markersArray.lenght);  
                                }   

                                // Opens info windows
                                function open_info_window(key, contentString) { 
                                    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                                        content: contentString
                                    });     

                                    alert(key);

                                    markersArray[key].info_window = infowindow;

                                    google.maps.event.addListener(markersArray[key].marker, "click", function() {
                                        markersArray[key].info_window.open(map, markersArray[key].marker);
                                    });
                                }
```

The part where I try to **alert(contentString)** will not alert what I expect and It's to do with closures but I actually have never come across such code before. Any chance you could give me a bit of help.

I want to be creating an infowindow with the contentString for the marker that i am adding.

Comment: What does the `open_info_window` function look like?  And `addMarker`?

Comment: i pasted in the top code now.. but it is not being called and is not relevant.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you'll see the result of the last iteration in the `alert`, this is explained in detail in [this blog post](http://www.mennovanslooten.nl/blog/post/62).

In your case, I would switch around the order of execution: You have an outer loop which calls `geocoder.geocode`:

```
for(a in elements) {
        var address = elements[a].location;                       
        (function (element) {
            geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                    doAlert(element);
                    addMarker(results[0].geometry.location);    
                } else {
                    alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
                }
            });
        })(elements[a]);
}
```

With function `doAlert`:

```
var doAlert = function(element) {
            var contentString = '<table>';

            for(b in element.other_fields){
                var current = element.other_fields[b];

                switch(current.type){
                    case "text":
                        contentString += "<tr><td class = 'the_title'>" + current.label + ":</td><td class = 'the_value'>" + current.values[0].value + "</td></tr>";
                    break;
                    case "date":
                        if(!current.values[0].end){
                            var end_date_output_string = "";
                        }else{ 
                            var end_date_output_string = " -> " + current.values[0].end;
                        }
                        contentString += "<tr><td class = 'the_title'>" + current.label + ":</td><td class = 'the_value'>" + current.values[0].start + end_date_output_string + "</td></tr>";
                    break;
                }
            }

            contentString += "</table>";  
            contentString += "<input type = 'button' onclick = 'window.open(\"" + elements[a].url + "\");' value = 'Open in Podio'>";

            alert(contentString);
      }
```

Comment: elements[a] always will equal the last one in the elements array and so the alert always says the same thing. that's the problem, the scope of the geocoder means that the index "a" cannot be seen by it.

Comment: I updated my answer, I see you've just now also found out about it :)

Answer (score 1):

YES, I FIGURED IT OUT

```
        function codeAddress(){
            for(a in elements){ 
                (function(a){   
                    var address = elements[a].location;  

                    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
                        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                            map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                            addMarker(results[0].geometry.location); 
                            alert(a);
                            var the_string = generate_string(elements, a);

                            infowindow[a] = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                                content: the_string
                            });     

                            google.maps.event.addListener(markersArray[a], "click", function() {
                                infowindow[a].open(map, markersArray[a]);
                            });
                        } else {
                            alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
                        }
                    });       
                })(a);        
            } 
        }
```

The trick was doing this and i have no idea how it works but it works:

```
(function(a){   
})(a);
```

I assume that a is the constructor for the function so that it doesnt get created by a variable reference but instead by the actual iterator itself. Oh god i dont know. yippee